# json to struct in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I have the following json:

```js
[
    {
      "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
      "Value": "7.8/10"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
      "Value": "89%"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Metacritic",
      "Value": "75/100"
    }
]
```

Is there a way to get BQ to be able to interpolate this as a struct? i.e., from the below it would be:

```js
/* relaxed 'tuple' syntax: */
[('Internet Movie Database', '7.8/10'), ...]

/* 'full' syntax: */
[
    STRUCT('Internet Movie Database' as Source, '7.8/10' as Value),
    STRUCT('Rotten Tomatoes' as Source, '89%' as Value),
    STRUCT('Metacritic' as Source, '75/100' as Value)
] as Reviews
```

Comment: How do you have the JSON in a column? exists in table? do you want perhaps to import?

Comment: @Pentium10 Oh it's just local as an example. Here would be a sample: https://gist.github.com/lisovskyvlad/26bb4ae3a49249566e8f59c8ddf2b2ec. For testing I'm using a `with temp as (...)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select 
  array(
    select as struct
      json_extract_scalar(rec, '$.Source') as Source, 
      json_extract_scalar(rec, '$.Value') as Value 
    from t.arr as rec
  ) as Reviews
from `project.dataset.table`, 
unnest([struct(json_extract_array(json) as arr)]) t
```

If applied to sample data from your question - output is

[image]

You can test above using below CTE

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '''
  [
      {
        "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
        "Value": "7.8/10"
      },
      {
        "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
        "Value": "89%"
      },
      {
        "Source": "Metacritic",
        "Value": "75/100"
      }
  ]
  ''' json
)
```

Comment: thanks, could you please show using the `with` statement, or how have you gotten your data 'into' BQ before running the query?

Comment: so a long story short, BQ doesn't really interpolate it, you must manually specify the struct from json (which would seem very tricky if it's a highly nested object!), is that correct?

Comment: you right. but for specific case with known schema - doable. with help of scripting and `execute immediate` ...